# Set NSToolbarItem Unselected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I am currently trying to define an `NSToolbar` with *selectable* `NSToolbarItems` which represent tools in a drawing OSX application. I want the user to be able to **select and deselect the tools(NSToolbarItems) to be used by clicking them**.

If you happen to know Sketch, that is the toolbar behaviour I am looking for:

[image: Selected Tool Screenshot]

In the image above you can see the "Edit" tool selected. If you click the item again, it gets deselected:

[image: Unselected Tool Screenshot]

I have been reading the Apple documentation for Toolbars and haven't found information about how to achieve this effect of being able to select / unselect toolbar items. In the "Selectable Toolbar Items" it says:

> Your application can specify the currently selected toolbar item using the method `setSelectedItemIdentifier:` passing the identifier for the desired toolbar item. The currently selected toolbar item is returned by the method `selectedItemIdentifier`. If there is no currently selected, nil is returned.

but I haven't found where the `setSelectedItemIdentifier:` method is defined or if it even is what will solve my requirement.

**What happens to my toolbar items now is that, once clicked, they can only be deselected by clicking another selectable item. Once an item is clicked, there will always be a selected item.**

Is there any simple way of getting this solved? am I missing an important part of the documentation where it explains how to achieve this effect?

Thanks a lot!

**ANSWER:**
So in the end it was as simple as setting the `selectedItemIdentifier` of the `NSToolbar` to `nil`. That causes the selected element to be deselected.

Comment: Would you mind answering your question in a separate answer to mark this question as answered?

Comment: There you go @Max! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In order to unselect an `NSToolbarItem`, it is as simple as setting the `selectedItemIdentifier` of the `NSToolbar` object to `nil`.

I was initially confused by Apple documentation, in the [Selectable Toolbar Items](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/SelectableItems.html) section, since it states that:

> [...] The currently selected toolbar item is returned by the method `selectedItemIdentifier`. If there is no currently selected, nil is returned.

so I thought `selectedItemIdentifier` was simply a method that returned the currently selected toolbar item (no setting, just getting). But I believe that should be a typo. `selectedItemIdentifier` is get/set property, and in fact, setting it to nil unselects all the items.